# Recursive CTE on Subset of Table Data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently have a table where each record has a Start Date and End Date. I need to create a separate table that shows all records and the months and years between the start and end dates.

I have created this recursive CTE query to do this but it is only returning one record out of the subset I need.  My question is how can I edit this so that it runs the recursive CTE on all records within the subset.

```
declare @start DATE
declare @end DATE 
declare @Opportunity Nvarchar(20)

SELECT  @start=eststartdate, @end=estcompletiondate, @opportunity=opportunity from opportunity where status='A'

;with months (Opportunity,Date)
AS
(
    SELECT @opportunity as Opportunity, DATEADD(DAY,1,EOMONTH(@start,-1))
    UNION ALL
    SELECT @opportunity as Opportunity,DATEADD(month,1,date)
    from months
    where DATEADD(month,1,date) < EOMONTH(@end)
)
select Opportunity, Datename(month,date),Year(date)
from months
```

Results would look something like this.

```
Opportunity1,  January, 2020
Opportunity1,  February, 2020
Opportunity1,  March, 2020
Opportunity2,  January, 2020
Opportunity2,  February, 2020
Opportunity2,  March, 2020
```

Comment: This is clearly SQL Server, so I added that tag.  Show the results you want.  Your question also makes no mention of `OpportunityId`, but that seems important.  I'm confused on what you actually want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the records for each opportunity, then you want something like this:

```
with months as (
      select o.opportunity, eststartdate as startdate, estcompletiondate as enddate
      from opportunity o left join
           OpportunityCustomTabFields oc
           on o.opportunityid = oc.opportunityid
      where o.status = 'A' and oc.custSFID IS NULL
      union all
      select opportunity, dateadd(month, 1, startdate), enddate
      from months
      where startdate < enddate
     )
select m.*
from months;
```

I don't understand several things about your question.  For instance, you describe a single table in the question, but your query has multiple tables.  You talk about dates, but then add `EOMONTH()` as if that were important.

However, the above should be close enough to what you want.  You may need to tweak it.  If you need additional help, I would recommend that you ask a *new* question with appropriate sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation.

Comment: I really appreciate it.  I removed the other table from the example. It was a join to define the subset a little better.  Not really relevant for my question so I took it out.  EOMONTH() I added because I was seeing some strange results with certain start and end dates.  I am going to try this and see if it works.

Comment: That was it.  Thank you Gordon.  I needed to teak the where clause to be    where DATEADD(month,1,startdate) < enddate
     )
select opportunity, Datename(month,startdate),Year(startdate)
from months;  But that did the trick.  If I had put the desired results in the question first that definitely would have been clearer.